# session_start();echo SID; outputs a blank page on refresh?

Tags: php, session

when I run this code for the first time

```
<?php
session_start();
echo SID;
?>
```

, I get some thing like:

```
PHPSESSID=9o2bhrqmln2j52caspdhholhk7
```

but when I refresh I get a  blank page

Until I remove the PHPSESSION cookie and start a new one ... is that normal or I have a problem ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[The manual](http://php.net/manual/en/session.idpassing.php) says:

> Alternatively, you can use the constant `SID` which is defined if the session started. If the client did not send an appropriate session cookie, it has the form `session_name=session_id`. **Otherwise, it expands to an empty string**. Thus, you can embed it unconditionally into URLs.

It's not meant to contain the session id, it's meant to be attached to URLs if cookies are disabled.

Comment: @Naughty To get the session id, use `session_id()`;

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is normal. this constant being populated only when no cookie present. Why do you think you have any problem? What's the use of this constant anyway?